# Cannot get Button location in Android App

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get the absolute location of my buttons after they have been drawn into view by the RelativeLayout. This is so that I can draw a pulsing glow animation at the location of the buttons. I have tried Button.getX(); and Button.getLocationOnScreen(); and both have returned an integer value of 0. I tried putting the buttons into a LinearLayout and was still unable to get coordinates for the button location on screen. I also tried running onPostCreate() to ensure the buttons were on screen before checking their location. I want to get their location on application boot, so theat I can create an animation to run underneath them. It seems that Button locations cannot be determined during onCreate. Anything I might be missing?

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button playButton = findViewById(R.id.play);
            System.out.println(playButton.getX());
            playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    play();
                }
            });

    playButton.getX();
    playButton.getY();

*OR*

    int playLoc = int[2] //<--- create two dimensional array for x and y 
    playLoc = playButton.getLocationOnScreen();
```

and The XML Layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/background"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--<com.example.macyg.androidmediaplayer.CustomView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#000000"/>-->

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/seekbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_play" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/forward"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/seekbar"
    android:layout_gravity="end"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/play"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_next" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/backward"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@id/seekbar"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/play"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
    android:shadowColor="@color/white"
    android:shadowRadius="50" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/aButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/backward"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="A" />

<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/bButton"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/seekbar"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/aButton"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="B" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/album_art"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/currTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="@string/default_time"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/trackLength"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:text="@string/default_time"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/album_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/artist_name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/songName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/album_art"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/artist_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/songName"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18sp" />
```

Comment: You should not use absolute pixel locations to place your buttons. Instead, look into ConstraintLayout (or any layout) to place your button as per its attribute settings like center vertical and center horizontal etc. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout Also adding a screenshot of what you want and what you have would help people understand your question properly. Also, please include your layout file in question.

Comment: Try using this instead probably the class was extended adding some stuffs `final AppCompatButton playButton = findViewById(R.id.play);` Change Button to AppCompatButton.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem. Rather than use the onPostCreate() method I use a post method (which is a function of the Button class) inside the onCreate() method to state that ***AFTER*** the button has been drawn into view by the relative layout so that I can get the locations of the buttons after they have been drawn in view. This is useful for when you run the application on devices with different screen sizes you will always know the coordinates of where the button was drawn.

[How get Button coordinate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906693/how-get-button-coordinate)

I hope this saves people the amount of time I spent trying to solve this! and thank you to Vektor88 for the solution!

Also here is the code in the onCreate setup phase. This worked correctly for me:

```
playButton = findViewById(R.id.play);
        playButton.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                playx = playButton.getX();
                playy = playButton.getY();
                System.out.println("play x = " + playx + " play y = " + playy);
            }
        });
```

**NOTE**

Why am I getting negative ratings on this post? I felt I gave very clear posts leading up to the answer and I don't feel I should have been answer banned.